# Aligning The Title, Autor, and Date in the header of a Beamer Poster

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, align, titles, beamerposter

I am using the beamer package and I have a title set at the top of the page, but I want to left align the title. So far I have this for the title portion:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\sepwid} \newlength{\onecolwid} \newlength{\twocolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} \setlength{\paperheight}{36in}
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.02\paperwidth} \setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth}
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
 \usetheme{confposter}
  \usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
  \graphicspath{{figures/}}

  \title{\begin{flushleft} TITLE \end{flushleft}}
  \author{ \begin{flushleft}NAME\end{flushleft}  }
  \institute{ \begin{flushleft} INSTITUTE \end{flushleft} }

  \begin{document} %% \end{document}
```

This compiles fine but it displays the results as such and I cannot figure out how to fix it. Suggestions? 
[image]

Comment: Instead of the code snippet you've provided, how about a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: Try with an empty beamer presentation, add only the minimal elements to show your issue so we know if you are using other packages, which themes, setting etc...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have changed the question to include a small working example as well as more detail on the problem it complies.

Comment: That's not an MWE. It will not produce the output you posted. Also, please provide a link for the theme as it is not in TeX Live. If I comment the theme out and add `abc` to the body, your code does NOT compile. You are surely ignoring errors galore to get any output at all!

Comment: You should tell `beamerposter` about the sizes rather than setting them manually e.g. `\usepackage[scale=1.24, size=custom, width=122, height=93]{beamerposter}`. You should never use explicit formatting markup in the arguments to commands such as `\title{}` (and this is the source of the enormous number of errors when you try to compile your code). The arguments should be *just* the ***plain text*** title, author etc.

Comment: How would that help me left align the title though? I thought that only helps define the overall size of the poster.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the confposter theme from http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/latex-poster-template/. If this is the case, simply redefine the `headline` template to use `\raggedright` instead of the default `\centering`

Original definition

```
 \setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}
```

The complete example with the modification:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \raggedright
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUTE}

\begin{document}
 test
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]